# Changing a csv file in powershell and exporting into a JSON

Tags: powershell

Im trying to change the structure of my csv file. The file has information about humidity in two of our offices.

The file looks like This:

```
Project: Test
Time: 02.08.2019 01:01
Name;room1;room2;
Description;desc_1;desc_2
Unit;%RH;%RH;
time1;value1room1;value1room2
time2;value2room1;value2room2
time3;value3room1;value3room2
time4;value4room1;value4room2
```

My goal is to have it to look something like that:

```
name;time;value
room1;time1;value1room1
room1;time2;value2room1
room1;time3;value3room1
room1;time4;value4room1
room2;time1;value1room2
room2;time2;value2room2
room2;time3;value3room2
room2;time4;value4room2
```

In the end i would also like to export it as a JSON file.

Is there any way to do that with Powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this for instance like this:

```
# read the file as string array
$txt = Get-Content -Path 'TheFileToConvert.txt'
# get the room names from the 3rd line
$parts = $txt[2] -split ';'
$room1 = $parts[1]
$room2 = $parts[2]

# loop through the data starting at the 6th line
$result = $txt[5..($txt.Count -1)] | ForEach-Object {
    $parts = $_ -split ';'
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        name = $room1
        time = $parts[0]
        value = $parts[1]
    }
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        name = $room2
        time = $parts[0]
        value = $parts[2]
    }
} | Sort-Object name, time

# output on screen
$result

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'TheOutput.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation

# output to JSON
$result | ConvertTo-Json
```

Output on screen as table:

```
name  time  value      
----  ----  -----      
room1 time1 value1room1
room1 time2 value2room1
room1 time3 value3room1
room1 time4 value4room1
room2 time1 value1room2
room2 time2 value2room2
room2 time3 value3room2
room2 time4 value4room2
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. Now everything gets shown but the timestamps are just randomly shown like:

`
room1;time1;value
room1;time4;value
room1;time2;value
room1;time3;value
`

Is there a way to show them like that:
`
time1
time2
time3
time4
`

Comment: @Jonas Please see the edited answer. You can sort on more than one property, so in your case `Sort-Object name, time`

Comment: Now everything work perfectly fine.
Thank you for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here should be a start:

```
$csvString = @"
Project: Test
Time: 02.08.2019 01:01
Name;room1;room2;
Description;desc_1;desc_2
Unit;%RH;%RH;
time1;value1room1;value1room2
time2;value2room1;value2room2
time3;value3room1;value3room2
time4;value4room1;value4room2
"@

$object = $csvString | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'

# do your stuff with the object here

# when your done:
$object | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File # output the json to some location
```